# how to check whether golang binary is compiled with --ldflags="-s -w"

Tags: go

i know `--ldflags="-s -w"` will make Go binary size smaller, but without comparing to the one without ldflags, how do we know whether Go binary compiled with or without `ldflags="-s -w"` ?

Comment: Why do you care?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Disclaimer first: I'm no expert of compilation toolchains and executable file formats. I'll try not to say stupid things, but correct me if you see any mistake !

I ran those tests on an ArchLinux laptop, with x86_64 architecture. Go version is 1.8.1.

First, we need to know where those flags are actually used:

```
$ go help build
...
-ldflags 'flag list'
    arguments to pass on each go tool link invocation
...
```

Apparently, flags are merely passed to the `go tool link` invocation. Looking at the help, we have a bit more information:

```
$ go tool link
...
-s  disable symbol table
...
-w  disable DWARF generation
...
```

Taken from the short introduction to ELF that I found [here](http://flint.cs.yale.edu/cs422/doc/ELF_Format.pdf), here is the header text concerning the Symbol Table:

> An object file’s symbol table holds information needed to locate and
>   relocate a program’s symbolic definitions and references.

As for DWARF, this is a format for debugging data.

From there, how do we know if a binary has a symbol table, or DWARF enabled ? The answer lies in ELF sections. There are probably other ways, but it is the one I found and is easy to check for. Here are the rules that I've used to determine if a Golang binary has been compiled with `-ldflags='-s'` or `-ldflags='-w'`:

- If a Go binary has a symbol table, the section `.symtab` is present
- If a Go binary has DWARF debug, the section `.debug_info` is present. This section is not the only one to be present, but serves as an indicator.

On Linux, there are some tools which can read section names to extract those informations. `readelf` and `nm` are examples, yet probably more exist.

It also turns out that Go provide a `debug/elf` package which can be used to get those informations. Here is a sample program that does this job:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "os"
import "debug/elf"

func main() {
    fileName := "path/to/main"
    fp, err := elf.Open(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    symtab := fp.Section(".symtab")
    if symtab == nil {
        fmt.Println("No Symbol Table : compiled with -ldflags='-s'")
    }

    debugInfo := fp.Section(".debug_info")
    if debugInfo == nil {
        fmt.Println("No DWARF data : compiled with -ldflags='-w'")
    }
}
```

I tested this program against the basic Golang Hello World, using no flags, only the `-s` flag, only the `-w` flag and both `-s -w` flags. I noted that while compiling with `-s` only, it also removed DWARF data, but I did not search why. Aside from that, the results were as expected.

Though ELF was the focus format, the same method can be applied for Windows executables (there is a `debug/pe` package in Golang).